# I'm having trouble setting up my email for my Mac, it's version 10.7.5

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I received my brother-in-law's old Mac as a gift. When we tried to switch from his email to mine, the app won't accept my password or connect online. Does anyone know to fix this? The Mac still has his name and email address as the default even though I've changed to my Apple ID and everything.

[image: I've changed all this to my email but yet]

[image: This is so frustrating]

I brought the Mac to my campus tech guy, but all he could suggest was hard resetting the computer, which is something I don't want to do.
If you need anymore photos for clarity, let me know and I'll be happy to edit my question with more.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove his account from the list of accounts in preferences.

- Go to **Mail** > **Preferences** [<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
- Go to the **Accounts** tab [Looks like an @ symbol]
- Select his old account
- Click the Minus button at the bottom of the list to remove his account [see picture below]

[image: Account settings]

- Now, add your email account.  *Note: Not to be confused with your Apple ID and password.  Even if your Apple ID is the same as your email, the passwords may be different.  One accesses Apple services (iCloud, iTunes etc.) the other is your email account.*

Comment: The iCloud password is the same as Mail - iTunes might differ

Comment: I switched his icloud account with mine and when i try to set up my gmail, it says connection failed @Mark

Comment: @Mark that depends. As she shows a gmail account in the screenshot the password for gmail should be entered. It is possible that the gmail account is also an Apple ID which (should for security reasons) be different. But not necessarily.

Comment: Sorry I meant AppleID for Apple Mail is iCloud the AppleID for iTunes might be the same boy the password could differ. AppleID is only for Apple